# How to put text on top of image (above)?

Tags: imagemagick, montage

I have came up with this:

```
montage -background Orange -label "Faerie Dragon" -gravity South test.png -geometry "100%" -font TREBUC.ttf -pointsize 25 out.png
```

It adds text "Fearie Dragon" with font Trebuchet in size 25 on orange background below the image test.png and doesn't scale original image.

The only problem is: how can I put the text above the image not below? `Gravity` option doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Your example ( except you are using montage instead of convert for some reason ) came from this page originally and it should answer your question: https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

Comment: They suggest on this page to change order or "images" but that doesn't do anything good- the label doesn't appear on the image.

Comment: It is the main Imagemagick example site and it is strange it does not work for you. But I can not add any other advice as you do not say what operating system you are using, how you are running the code or show a copy of the code you are using now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the annotation on the upper side of the image using convert `instead` of `montage` with the following command:

```
convert test.png -pointsize 25 -gravity North -background Orange -splice 0x32 -annotate +0+4 "Faerie Dragon" out.png
```

This is the output of your command with `montage`:

[image]

This is the output of the command with `convert`:

[image]

Starting from a 400x300 image both commands generate a 400x332 image.

*Tested with ImageMagick 7.0.5-3 on Windows*

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks a lot!